# Django - how to cache template for all url prefix

Tags: django, caching, redis, django-views, django-templates

I have a Django app which renders html template and loads data into html via ajax from front end(based on url's dynamic id).
For eg., this is my site's dynamic url pattern "www.mysite.com/order/**< some dynamic id>**", I want django to cache & return all the requests to this url prefix r"^**[www.mysite.com/order/**"](http://www.mysite.com/order/**%22) to render the html without hitting my views function.

Currently, each dynamic id in the url pattern ("/order/100","/order/101","/order/102..etc")is coming to my views and rendering the same template for each.

I'm expecting, anyone visits with prefix "/order/" the html template needs to be rendered automatically without hitting my views. I'm currently using redislite for caching, Please help me with a solution.

**UPDATE** : It seems using a front-end framework like React or Angular JS will solve my "avoiding html template rendering" case with django. I didn't wanted django to waste time on rendering html, so I thought of caching the templates.

Comment: If the order is dynamic, are you showing dynamic data in the template? If so, you can't cache it. If you cache it, the content will be the same for each order.

Comment: the html template has a javascript which will make ajax call on load and the ajax will populate the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can [cache per-view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache) using `cache_page`. This may be most appropriate for what you're trying to do.

```py
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

@cache_page(60 * 15)  # 15 mins
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Or you can cache fragments of templates, where you use the `cache` template tag and a time (in seconds) to cache the block of markup;

```
{% load cache %}

{% cache 500 sidebar %}
    .. sidebar ..
{% endcache %}
```

This type of caching can be as simple as above, or you can do more complex caching by varying on the logged in user, for example. You can read the docs on that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching)

Comment: my url conf is like `path('order/<id>/', views.orders)` and my views function is like `@cache_page(60 * 15) def orders(request,id): return render(request, page.html)`.. will it cache it only once or it will cache for each new id?

Comment: As you'll see in the linked docs, `cache_page` caches based on the URL, so each ID will be separate.